# How to iterate over neural network architectures?

Tags: python, automation, neural-network

I've been handed a file with over 30 different neural network architectures, which I should examinate regarding certain metrics. Basically, without calling every single network explicitly, i.e. "MapNet1()", I want to iterate over the networks and just track the metrics I'm interested in.
How do I do that, especially regarding even bigger sizes of networks to investigate? Or better formulated: how can I loop over the networks defined in my file "classification_models.py" and the networks defined in there without calling each of the networks manually?

All the best.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how the models are defined in `classification_models.py`? This would be helpful in parsing  them.

Answer (score 1):

Make a python list, which entries are yours neural networks (for example, append the trained models one by one). Then iterate over the list as usual.